# How to get current time from network time protocol?

Tags: android, ntp

Actually, in my application, some login expiry time is there but if the user changes device time, date settings it is not working properly, I wanted to get network time using NTP. For this, I am hitting google.com, but this is also not the proper way as per location coordinates. So is there any way to get accurate time based on location using NTP

https://developers.google.com/time/

Answer (score 0):

No, NTP does not use location specific time (timezones).  It uses UTC.